# Java check for null practise

Tags: java

Usual practice I have seen so far is to check like this:

```
if (object != null) {...}
```

But today I have encountered the following situation:

```
if (object) {...}
```

Are these two lines COMPLETELY equivalent? The latter seems little bit strange to me, since the object is not neccesary a Boolean. Is it better(shorter) to write in latter way?

Comment: if ( object ) ... this seems rather JavaScript then Java. Unless 'object' translates to a conditional statement, in Java it won't compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely not.

The `if (object)` syntax will **only** work if `object` is an instance of primitive `boolean`, and by proxy, wrapper class `Boolean` (auto-unboxed).

Also note that the `if (object)` syntax will work with weaker typed languages such as Groovy or JavaScript, with all caveats implied.

Finally note that a `Boolean` wrapper is also nullable in Java, hence the `if (object != null)` syntax would actually make sense too for `Boolean`s (but wouldn't compile for primitive `boolean`s).

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
if (object) {...}
```

is **not java** syntax, but javascript.

In java that code works only if `object` is of type `Boolean` and is not `null`.